# execute thread periodically and stop it after condition is met or time is over

Tags: java, java-threads

I want to execute a thread periodically to check if some file is ready for uploaded and upload it as soon as it is ready then stop the thread immediately. Also, if a long time has passed I want to stop the thread regardless the file not being ready, but can't do it inside the run method itself.

```
    final ScheduledFuture<?> fileUploadedFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        try {
            if (fileReady("xyz.txt")) {
                uploadFile("xyz.txt")
                //cancel fileUploadedFuture and fileUploadedFutureCanceller
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }, 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    final ScheduledFuture<?> fileUploadedFutureCanceller = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        fileUploadedFuture.cancel(true);
    }, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: You can use watchService in java refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1):

How about using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

```
public class TestExecutor {
    private static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    private static class PushFile implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (new File("test.txt").exists()) {
                System.out.println("found it!");
                exec.shutdown();
            } else {
                System.out.println("waiting");
            }
        }

    }

    private static class ShutMeDown implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("timeout");
            exec.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new PushFile(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        exec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ShutMeDown(), 10, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I could just shut down my scheduler, but the scheduler is not local and it's used for other purposes, so I'd like to just kill just the right threads and not shut down the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

@laughing buddha suggested a watcher. It's probably more resource-efficient than my first suggestion, but I'm not entirely sure it's the right solution in this case, because you're still parking a thread. Nevertheless, I coded a test, and it's short and easy to read, so you may as well have the code:

```
public class TestWatchService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path file = Paths.get(".");
        WatchKey key = file.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        List<WatchEvent<?>> events = new ArrayList<>();
        for (boolean done = false; ! done; events = key.pollEvents()) {
            if (events.size()==0) {
                System.out.println("waiting");
                Thread.sleep(2000L);
            } else {
                System.out.println("got it!");
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: test by touching any new file in the current directory. Code will have to be updated to check for specific filenames, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, but I'm not really interested in the file part. That was just an example.